# How to Integrate Tagsys RFID reader in Flutter web app?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, rfid

I have a tagsys RFID reader and I want to use this reader to get information about any book that I have with tag.

I've searched but not found any plugin or tutorial for this.

Can anyone please help me in this problem as this is my college project and I'm stuck here.

I'm making a flutter web app.

Comment: What is the reference of your reader?

Comment: I don't know much about that but my college has some of them for library so it's Tagsys RFID reader but I just wanna know how to connect some external RFID reader and take input.